# Customise SelectedTextColor of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to customize the selectedTextColor of `UITextField`?
Default is blue color.

[image]

The UITextField delegates/notification only handles when there is text change:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
- UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are targeting iOS7+, you can just set the `tintColor` of the text field:

```
textField.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
```

You can also set this globally in your app by using an appearance proxy (so you don't need to do it for each field):

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

It can also be done individually in Interface Builder, on the attribute inspector, under View -> Tint Color.